# Change color of fixed background image when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

After multiple hours of search, I haven't found any solution.

What I want to do is quite simple : my page has a fixed background image so it doesn't move when I scroll down/up, this is ok. But since my page is divided in sections (it's kind of a CV, so sections like skills, pro exp, etc), i'd like the background image to **smoothly** change its coloration when the user scrolls, so the color is different for each sections.

Unfortunately I don't know any website that behaves this way so I can't provide any example.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? => https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV

Comment: @HenryLy Not really sionce I use a picture as a background. But the idea is here. Just, instead of colorizing the bg itself, i want to colorize the picture.

Comment: Do you want a color that superimposes the image in opacity mode?

Comment: If it can be done without overlapping the rest of the page (ie all the content), i think it might do the job

Comment: What colors do you want your image to take? Upload an example

Comment: @alessandrio Well, it's exactly like the link provided in first answer. Imagine my picture being colored in blue when you're at the top of the page, then when you scroll down, it turns red, then if you keep scrolling yellow, etc. And it would work backward. (Can't provide any example atm)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you wish to colorize will determine the method. If the colorizing is complex, as only photoshop can do, then you should make several versions of it and place them in your elements as

`background-attachment: fixed;`

...and keep the same background-position for all of them.

If you only want a transparent, colored overly, this can be done with CSS and transparent, background colors: `rgba()`.

HTML

```
<main-background>
  <section-one></section-one>
  <section-two></section-two>
  <section-three></section-three>
  <section-four></section-four>
  <section-five></section-five>
</main-background>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
main-background {
  display: flex;
  background: url(https://cdn.cjr.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/AdobeStock_100000042-e1563305717660-1300x500.jpeg) no-repeat fixed 50% 50% / cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;

  > * {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: calc(100%/3);
    min-height: 75%;
  }
}

section-one {
  background: rgba(234,123,213,0.3)
}

section-one {
  background: rgba(234,123,213,0.3)
}

section-two {
  background: rgba(234,123,0,0.3)
}

section-three {
  background: rgba(0,123,213,0.3)
}

section-four {
  background: rgba(0,0,132,0.3)
}

section-five {
  background: rgba(111,222,0,0.3)
}
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/yLybMRz

Comment: The problem with overlapping a transparent color is that i'd need it not to cover the text. I need it to apply only on the background, not the whole page.